# My Flat-list doesn't show any data in React-Native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I have a link that produce JSON data from my Google Spreadsheet and I Just trying to display that data into my Flat-List View Component but I don't know why It not showing any data into My Flat-List

This is my JSON data which I get from my Spreadsheet

```
{"Arbaz":[{"id":1,"name":"Arbaz","roll":12},{"id":2,"name":"Imtiyaz","roll":34},{"id":3,"name":"John","roll":45},{"id":3,"name":"James","roll":23}]}
```

And this is my React Native code:

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {


 state = {
    data: []
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    //const response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api?results=10");
    const response = await fetch("MYLINK");
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ data: json.results });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Nothing to show</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
          
            <Text>
              {`${item.data.Arbaz.id} ${item.data.Arbaz.id}`}
            </Text>}
        />
        
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: This is my Output Screen]

Comment: Does your json actually contain a `results` key? if not it would just be `{data:json}`

Comment: **Thank you so much** I forget about that. Now It work fine